# Trying to Compare 2 Tables with Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compare 2 tables, but can't seem to get it to work.  It's probably something very basic.  Here's my code:

```
Select bin, partno, count(*) from 
(SELECT parts.partno, location.bin
    FROM inventory
    INNER JOIN location
        ON inventory.locid = location.locid
    INNER JOIN parts
        ON inventory.partid = parts.partid
WHERE  loc = 'PnP'
UNION             
select partno, bin from dlyfeedercontents) t
Group By t.bin, t.partno
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY bin
```

Here are the results:

```
08-01   3052-93-7100-0C6    1
08-01   3052-93-7100-0C6    1
08-01   Test2               1
08-02   3052-90-7100-063    1
08-02   3052-90-7100-063    1
```

I can't seem to get the Group or Count to acknowledge that there are duplicates (for example, the first 2 lines).  The results of the UNION are what I expected.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: I'll work on it now.

Comment: I'll have a sqlfiddle in the morning.

Comment: I've never used sqlfiddle before, but here's the link.                   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/735ef5/2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but I strongly suspect the problem is using `union` rather than `union all`.  `union` removes duplicates.  Does this version do what you want?

```
select bin, partno, count(*) 
from ((SELECT parts.partno, location.bin
       FROM inventory INNER JOIN
            location
            ON inventory.locid = location.locid INNER JOIN
            parts
            ON inventory.partid = parts.partid
       WHERE loc = 'PnP'
      ) union all
      (select partno, bin
       from dlyfeedercontents
      )
     ) t
Group By t.bin, t.partno
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY bin;
```

Comment: Same results as originally listed.

Comment: If `UNION` removes duplicates, why does he have duplicates in the result?

Comment: `GROUP BY` also removes duplicates, yet he still has duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I think you missed this in the question:  "I can't seem to get the Group or Count to acknowledge that there are duplicates ".  The `group by` is *after* the `union`, so the duplicates are already removed.

Comment: I saw that. If you look at his output, he has duplicate rows, but `UNION` and `GROUP BY` should combine them.

Comment: I suspect there's some non-printing characters in his data, causing the rows to appear like duplicates when they actually aren't.

Comment: I've created a SQLFiddle so you can see a subset of the data.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/735ef5/2

Comment: You realize that the last two values confuse the upper case letter "o" with zero.

Comment: I had a typo in my data on SQLFiddle, but Barmar is the winner.  I found a '/r' in some of the data.  This resulted in what appeared to be duplicates.  As usual something basic.....

Comment: @Barmar should translate his comment into an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a nonprinting character in some of the data (/r)!  Thanks for all who helped!